# Eclipse C Build selected files generates no executable

Tags: c, eclipse, cygwin

I'd like to build a single C file on Windows using Eclipse Helios and Cygwin. I rightclick on the file, select "Build selected file", the console output returns but I can't find an executable. I can't use the build project function because I have multiple folders with different applications. (for example it complains that I have more than one main function)

Console output:

Rebuilding selected file(s)

> **** Internal Builder is used for build               **** gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -ofolder\test.o ..\folder\test.c
>
> Build of selected resources is complete.

Build and Run works when I have just one src folder with a single Hello World file for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you're rebuilding a specific file you're only rebuilding the corresponding object file. There's nothing strange about this.

From gcc manual page:

> When you invoke GCC , it normally does preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking. The "overall options" allow you to stop this process at an intermediate stage. For example, the -c option says not to run the linker. Then the output consists of object files output by the assembler.

Comment: Then what is the solution to building and running a single file?

Comment: It seems to me that if you have multiple main functions, it's an indication that your project structure isn't that great. But I guess you could write manual build instructions for different targets. If you just need a quickfix you could test running the gcc command in a terminal, but omitting the -c parameter.

Answer (score 0):

the `-c` in the build statement will only compile, not link so no executable will be generated.  However, an object file will be placed in `../folder`  named `test.o`